# How do I run tests under a certain folder?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I'd like to be able to run all the tests under a folder structure like below.  Anything under "tests" I would like to run.  Is this possible?

We have a bunch of other tests in our project that haven't been maintained.  We're migrating tests into this new tests folder.

Would a test category work?

[image: Nested tests in folders]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since VS2012 SP1, there are new test filters. You can use them to run your tests.

[image: test filters]

Of course, you could also use a Category for this : you just need to tag every test class.